# StringToBytes Issue in Expect Script

Tags: expect

I am using the below command in my Expect script file.

set name [StringToBytes "Tamin"];
puts "name = $name"

When i run this script, i get the below error.

invalid command name "StringToBytes"
while executing
"StringToBytes "Tamin""
invoked from within
"set name [StringToBytes "Tamin"]"

Can anyone please help me to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this means that the command `StringToBytes` could not be found.  `StringToBytes` is not listed in the [documentation](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/contents.htm), so presumably you intended to define this command yourself?

Comment: The documentation shows only TCL commands. I hope this is a command in Expect script.

Comment: Can anyone let me know to fix it?

Comment: agree with fbarber, this isn't a standard TCL command (Expect is a TCL extension, not really a language of itself.)  'StringToBytes' appears to be performing some sort of string conversion here- if you know what it's converting, you could build the missing function (proc).

Comment: I would like to know whether "StringToBytes" is an expect keyword/function?